# How do I edit the list of file templates that show up when I create a new file?

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I've created several file templates, but the list seems to be too long and gets truncated.  There are several default templates that I don't use that I would like to remove them from the list, or at least reorder, so mine are at the top.

Alternatively, is there a way to open a file template from the action center?

Comment: Are you refering to this? [Creating and Editing File Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-and-editing-file-templates.html)

Comment: nope.  I've created them just fine.  There just isn't any way to access them when I try to create a new file. The list only contains 9 templates, but there are a total of 20 file templates

Comment: ok, it seems it's the templates I edited that aren't showing up.  If I duplicate those and rename them, then they are showing up.  still strange

Comment: Screenshots please: 1) what you see in `New` menu and 2) what templates you are trying to edit (that do not show up). I'm 99.99% sure you just doing it wrong (do not understand how the system works). Duplicating/Renaming is not the right way for sure.